# Localhost 8080 will not update on VSCode save

Tags: npm, localhost, npm-start

I've never encountered this before. I startup localhost: 8080 using npm start, and it loads just fine. However, when I edit my code and save, the browser page isn't updated either automatically nor on refresh. The only resolution I've found is shutting down the localhost and starting anew.

I've shut down VSCode and Google Chrome and have used different ports (8080, 8081, 8082). I've looked elsewhere, as well as fellow colleagues but I've run up dry.

Comment: When auto-refresh-on-save worked, was it instances on systems? You probably have some config or setting that makes a difference. (Or check error logs, maybe it wants to sync, but doesn't).  [If you are certain the server is saving, you should use URL utility that requests a cache-bypassing request (like curl or wget)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I spent a ton of time searching but found it was due to having my file in the Windows folder vs. Linux sub-system in WSL. New to all this and I've had some odd quirks, but everything has mostly worked fine up until now. I'm wondering now if the other quirks are because of this.